# Swift4 ViewController not fired event in subView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

I have 1 MainViewController from storyboard and 1 ModalUIView from xib.

In ModalUIView has present function for displaying modal and dismiss function for closing modal.

Step:
MainViewController -> OpenModal -> ModalUIView -> CloseModal

Here are my code:

UIViewUtil.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    // Load xib as the same name of CustomView that want to use xib
    func loadXib() -> UIView{
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nibName = type(of: self).description().components(separatedBy: ".").last!
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    }
}
```

MainViewController.swift is subclass of UIViewController

```
@IBAction func guideButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let modal = ModalUIView()
    modal.present(targetView: self.view)
}
```

ModalUIView.swift is subclass of UIView

```
var view : UIView?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setup()
}

func setup() {
    view = loadXib()
}

func present(targetView: UIView) {
    view!.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    view!.clipsToBounds = true

    targetView.addSubview(view!)

    // Set size
    let popupWidth: CGFloat = targetView.frame.width - (targetView.frame.width * 0.04)
    let popupHeight: CGFloat = targetView.frame.height - (targetView.frame.height * 0.08)

    view!.frame = CGRect(x: targetView.frame.origin.x, y: targetView.frame.origin.y,
                         width: popupWidth, height: popupHeight)

    view!.center = targetView.center

    view!.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    view!.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4){
        self.view!.alpha = 1
        self.view!.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}

@objc func dismiss(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("dismiss")
}
```

My problem is mainViewController when I called present of modalUIView and then I tab on closeButton in modalUIView is not fired the action

I try with @IBAction but it not work:

```
@IBAction func CloseButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

I also try with manual add action by programmatically but it not work too:

```
let closeButton: UIButton? = view?.viewWithTag(10) as! UIButton
closeButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismiss), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Note: 
I can see and tap on closeButton on modal.
I already add ModalUIView to xib File's Owner

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a solution now but not sure that is the best answer.

My solution is to add an action to closeButton of modalUIView via mainViewController not in modalUIView

If anyone have another best solution than this please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get an action in your viewcontroller following.

```
yourSubView.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPress(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and it will call your method.

```
func buttonPress(sender:UIButton){
print("Button pressed")
}
```